# Adding mimetypes in servicesatck

Tags: servicestack

How would one add custom MIME types to a servicestack application?

I tried searching servicestack.net and peeking in the source code, but i seems that it is not a common requirement to change MIME types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm` for an example on how to use custom MIME types i.e. custom content-type.